# Power BI Report Server Jan 2019 hyperlinks

Tags: microsoft-powerbi

After upgrading company's Power BI Report Server from Aug 2018 to Jan 2019 version, hyperlinks no longer change color after visited. In previous versions, users would click on a link for the 1st time, and the link would change from blue to purple. This helps users know that they have already visited a link. This no longer works, have researched for days online, till now have found nothing. Asked in Microsoft Power BI forums but yet no answers.